# Динамическое добавление столбцов в форму

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Есть базовая форма для списков. Написал процедуру, которая вызывает табличную функцию нужного списка в зависимости от переданного параметра idTab. В отображаемых списках 4 колонки одинаковые, остальные отличаются названием, кол-ом данных и общим кол-ом. Первые 4 я добавляю статически в дизайнере, а как можно добавлять остальные динамически, в зависимости от выбранного списка?

Comment: DataGridView? Данные ты сам генеришь или берешь откуда-то? Если берешь, то как подгружаешь, через присваивание Items или через DataSource?

Comment: @Andrew Да, DataGridView, беру из таблиц, через DataSource

Comment: Вообще, действия, которые Вы выполняете в дизайнере, записываются в виде кода в файл вида `<имя_формы>.Designer.cs`. Там можно посмотреть код, который добавляет первые четыре столбца и на его основе написать свой.

Comment: А чтобы Вам смогли ответить здесь нужно расписать вопрос поподробнее. Составьте пример, укажите по шагам, что именно Вы делаете, а то из рассказа детали неясны. И еще, при чем здесь DevExpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если учесть что:

- DataGridView
- ассайн данных через DataSource

Должно быть как-то так, но не проверял:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();// инициализируем колонку

column.DataPropertyName = "Name";//имя
column.Name = "Knight"; //заголовок колонки
column.DataPropertyName = "GoodGuy";//привязка к проперти обьекта который нужно отображать
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```